# Can't initialize plugin (isotope) when using jQuery.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

So I've created an app that loads HTML on a clients page and I need to load a few scripts via javascript and act on the HTML. In particular I need to use JS to get the isotope javascript file and then initialize it on the HTML we just created.

Also note that I am running jQuery in noConflict mode so the scripts don't cause errors on the clients site. In testing my code works fine if I hardcode the < script > tag in the HTML, but this isn't feasible on the final product. I need to get the external script via JS since it's dynamic. The problem is I get the following error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"**

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m87xuoo/1/)

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      div.item {width:200px; height:200px; background:#039; margin:10px;}
    </style>

    <div id="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      ch_jquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        ch_jquery.getScript('http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.min.js', function(){
          $('#container').isotope();    
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For starters you didn't included the jQuery library in your jsfiddle example.
Then you shall define the `jQuery.noConflict` outside of the `$(document).ready()` function. [This is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6m87xuoo/5/).

```
var ch_jquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$( document ).ready(function() {
        ch_jquery.getScript('http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.min.js', function(){
      $('#container').isotope();    
    });
});
```

EDIT
An another example with noconflict would be this one

```
var ch_jquery = jQuery.noConflict();
ch_jquery( document ).ready(function() {
            ch_jquery.getScript('http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.min.js',     function(){
                ch_jquery('#container').isotope();    
            });
        });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6m87xuoo/6/)

Comment: I included the jQuery under "External Resources". I didn't realize it needed to be under "Frameworks". Thanks. 

You are not using "ch_jquery" for your isopote initialization or your (document).ready function. When I use "ch_jquery" instead of "$" it breaks. Why did you opt to use teh "$" and won't that cause conflict if there are multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: yeah, so the question remains though, in your example (due to the `true` boolean) you are dereferencing every jQuery related variables like the documentation says
`A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the global scope (including jQuery itself).`
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: It also says: `If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.` This is essentially what I want to do. Leave all predefined jQuery references to work as normal, and have a new jQuery variable "ch_jquery" for all my specific JS I need to run.